# How to display an image from a byte array representing the very bytes of a .png file

Tags: wpf, image, file, png, arrays

I have a byte array that is the very copy of a .png file in memory and I have to display it in a WPF ImageControl. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Memory Stream from the array, load the image from the stream, then set the Image in the control.